# What is the field of view for the human eyes?

Tags: vision, human-eye

I'd like to know how much a person can see regarding the angles.

If it is a rectangle, I'd like to know it's height and width.

But if is another shape, I'd like to know which kind of shape and the angles.

I suppose that we can see something like this and if this is true I am curious about 4 dimensions:

- "vertical" angle for both eyes
- "horizontal" angle for both eyes
- "vertical" angle for an eye
- "horizontal" angle for an eye

[image]

It would be also nice if there will be some "areas" with percentages. I mean, something related to "central" vs "peripheral" view, because we see better something that is in front of us than something that is near us.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **general shape** of the field of view has been answered in the related question "[If human eyes watch an area, what's the shape of its capturing shape? Rectangular? Half spherical?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24046/if-human-eyes-watch-an-area-whats-the-shape-of-its-capturing-shape-rectangula/24048#24048)"

Regarding the central view: yes, **foveal view has a higher acuity** than peripheral view.

Regarding the numerical dimensions of the monocular and binocular field of view: **Monocular field of view  (measured from central fixation) is 160 deg (width w) x 175 deg (height h)**. The total **binocular field of view is 200 deg (w) x 135 deg (h)**.

The region of **binocular overlap is 120 deg (w) x 135 deg (h)** ([WebVision](http://webvision.med.utah.edu/book/part-xiii-facts-and-figures-concerning-the-human-retina/)). The **binocular foveal high-acuity part** (central view) is about **[6 degrees](http://neuronresearch.net/vision/reading/foveola.htm) (5-15 degrees)**.

Comment: Chris what does the `w` signify in the brackets? Does it stand for width and `h` for height? Or does `h` stand for horizontal and `w` meant for vertical?

Comment: w x h = width x height, question edited. thankx

Comment: Good answer so +1. Though it would be more useful if you can split the monocular vision angle in horizontal direction as nasal and temporal fields

Comment: @CRags - the linked question covers nasal/temporal aspects. And thanx :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check that question Chris

Comment: One thing that's interesting is that the optical system is not just encoding image feature details (like a camera), but also has built-in low-level filtering that can detect motion with reduced latency compared to the pathway used for feature detection.  This is relevant when considering vision as an ongoing process, since the eyes are typically [constantly moving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccade), with a choice of focal point partially motivated by motion detected in the periphery.