# What is the field of view of humans (not just fixed angle eyes)?

Tags: vision, eyes

What is the human field of view also counting the maximum vertical and horizontal eye movement (rotation), with the head still.

It is unclear from this question whether the answer relates to the field of view from both eyes when a person is looking at a fixed angle or also what he/she can see if the head won't rotate but the eyes will.
[What is the field of view for the human eyes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28138/what-is-the-field-of-view-for-the-human-eyes)

There are many articles and diagrams online as well but they too don't make it clear whether the eye rotations are also taken into account or not and it is just the FOV at any given moment at a given eye angle.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure the question you linked assumes fixed head position and includes eye movement. Eye rotation is taken into account.

Comment: @Diio - why do you assume that?